# awk code cannot end automatically until I press CTRL+D

Tags: awk

I have a simple awk code, like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFMT="%.0f"} {print 18.23}'
```

But after I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, there is nothing.  I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> again, then I get the result 18, but it will not end automatically until I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

After I change the code to be like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFMT="%.0f";print 18.23}'
```

then it works fine.

I don't know the reason for such a difference.  My understanding: {print 18.23} is an action, but why is there no problem after I move to the part of BEGIN?

Comment: ["*The basic function of awk is to search files for lines (or other units of text) that contain certain patterns. When a line matches one of the patterns, awk performs specified actions on that line. awk continues to process input lines in this way until it reaches the end of the input files.*"](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getting-Started) Your action is performed on every line of input.

Answer (score 2):

`{print ...}` in first `awk` script is referred to as *main input loop*. The actions you write in this block to do the processing assume that there is a line of input available. As there is no file specified it waits for user input. To terminate it on first iteration you have to call `exit` manually. That's why you can see below piped `awk` works as you expected:

```
echo "" | awk 'BEGIN {OFMT="%.0f"} {print 18.23;}'
```

There are three major blocks in `awk`:

- `BEGIN {}` Once at beginning
- `{}` Executed on each input line
- `END {}` Once at end of proccessing

These are pictured in this image coming from O'Reilly *sed & awk* book:

[image]

Comment: thanks, now i understand, print in the first awk script wil assume to loop not only once(wait for manual input) if there is no file specified,